# mosquitto MQTT: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using c# MQTT Client
clientSub = new MqttClient("raspberrymachine100");

and when I connect with this C# client, I get the error {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.12.134:1883"}

But when I use the same C# client and connect to host test.mosquitto.org I am able to connect.

Additionally, when I use the mosquittto installed client
"C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\mosquitto_sub" -h 192.168.12.134 -p 1883 -d -t /topic/test
This above line works fine and I can subscribe

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of mosquitto are you using on the Raspberry Pi? the version in the default repository is very out of date. If you are using that one you should try getting hold of the latest version

Comment: Also as a quick test, try a shorter client ID

Comment: Not what version of the protocol, what actual build version of the mosquitto broker

Comment: 1. I have started the mosquitto server in a command line root@raspberrypi:~# mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto
1428258655: mosquitto version 0.15 (build date 2013-01-09 05:15:05+0000) starting
1428258655: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1428258655: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1428258655: Warning: Address family not supported by protocol

2. This is the ProtocolVersion "Version_3_1_1" I see from the C# client and I have also added a test Client ID

3. I see on my command line a message as the c# client connects showing "Invalid protocol "MQTT" in CONNECT from 192.168.2.29."

Answer (score 10):

I had the that problem. I saw a solution (in Windows), and it helped me.

Go to Services (it is also called  Services.msc) and search for the "Mosquitto Broker" service, and click on "start (the) service".

[image: service_window_picture]

Answer (score 1):

The version of Moquitto you are running is very old (the latest is 1.4.1) and I think that version only supports protocol 3.0 not 3.1.1

Best bet will be to upgrade to the version 1.4.1. There are details on how to add a new apt repository to get the latest version on the mosquitto download page here: http://mosquitto.org/download/

Comment: hardillb - many thanks for the info. I ran the steps below and YEAH, its working now..Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help from one of the folks on this forum (hardillb), I realized that my version of mosquitto did not support protocol 3.1.1. After updating --by running the commands below - it has solved the connection problem on my RaspberryPi with Derbian

```
wget http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-repo.gpg.key
sudo apt-key add mosquitto-repo.gpg.key
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo wget http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-wheezy.list
apt-get update
apt-get install mosquitto
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I could solve it by installing an older version of mosquitto
The latest version (mosquitto-1.4.15a-install-win32) wasn't working (also when I tried to start the mosquitto broker service with "net start mosquitto" I got the error "the service is not responding to the control function"). I installed the version mosquitto-1.3.5-install-win32^and now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

By default mosquito only listens on localhost. To establish a remote connection you need a config file...

```
    > cat /etc/mosquito/conf.d/README 
    > Any files placed in this directory
    > that have a .conf ending will be loaded as config files by the broker.
    > Use this to make your local config.
```

So, if we create a file called (for example) mqtt.conf in /etc/mosquito/conf.d that includes these lines...

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true # you might want to think about the security implications
```

...then when we restart the service this will be used as the service config...

```
> sudo systemctl stop mosquito
> sudo systemctl start mosquito
> sudo systemctl status mosquito
```

...and we should see this reflected in the service status...

```
Starting mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker...
Loading config file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mqtt.conf
Started mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
```

...and you should now be able to connect remotely by citing your broker's hostname as the client connection in this simple publisher...

```
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
    
    client = mqtt.Client("publisher")
    
    client. Connect("your MQTT broker's hostname goes here")
    
    client. Publish("test","hello world")
```

...using this simple subscriber...

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from time import sleep

def message_received(client, userdata, message):
    print(message. Topic)
    print(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    
client = mqtt.Client("subscriber")

client. Connect("your MQTT broker's hostname goes here")

client.on_message = message_received

client. Subscribe("test")

client.loop_start()

print("waiting...")

while True:
    sleep(1)
```

Luck.

Comment: The question is about c# not python, and as discussed in the other answers the version of the broker the OP was using didn't support MQTT v3.1 which is what the client code was trying to connect with.